# How to change the fill color of a shape using an excel 2013 button in vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to develop an excel version of a baseball scorecard with diamonds representing first through third base and a pentagon for home plate.

Currently I'm working with just the first players batting and base running information in the first inning and will copy the working code to the rest of the other players and in the other innings.  I've placed hidden buttons on top of each base, a button on top of the Out circle, four buttons for balls and three buttons for strikes.

1. The gist is that when a ball or strike is thrown, the respective button is clicked and the buttons back color will change to *dark grey*.  If the player is out, the button on top of the out circle is clicked and fills the circle with *black* color.  For each base the runner makes it to safely, the button is clicked and the base is filled with *black* color.  When the home plate button is clicked if fills home plate with *black* color and increases the score in the home score box by one.  Will this work and if so, will someone please help me with the VBA portion of each event?
2. If for any reason, a mistake is made, the respective button can be clicked again and will undo the previous clicks actions.
3. The method I will use for testing is clicking each button to see the response and effect.  If the first players buttons work without affecting the other players, I will move on to the next player to see if any previous button is affected by clicking that players buttons. So on and so forth until I reach the last player in the last inning.  I'm assuming that I will not have to test each individual players buttons and that after three or four players working correctly that all players buttons will work correctly.

**I'm using MS Excel 2013 and ActiveX buttons for the bases and the Out circle and form buttons for the balls and strikes.

Comment: what is your actual question? Please share some screenshot and relevant code what you've already developed? Please ask a specific question (it's not clear now how title is related to your question).

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what assistance you need.  This code will create a button on the worksheet:

```
Sub Creator()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1, 100, 10, 60, 60)
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Press Me"
    shp.Name = "MyButton"
End Sub
```

After the Shape has been created, assign this macro to it:

```
Sub ButtonPressCode()
    Dim shp As Shape, R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("MyButton")
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        R = .RandBetween(1, 255)
        G = .RandBetween(1, 255)
        B = .RandBetween(1, 255)
    End With
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)
End Sub
```

with each click of the button, the shape will change color:

[image]